# Change a state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and as a learning exercise am trying to do a very basic page where there is a form and you put text in an input box, you click submit and the header changes to what you entered. Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {header: 'yeaheheh'}
  }
  changeHeader(e) {
    let newHeader = document.getElementById('input').value();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
    this.setState(newHeader);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h1>{this.state.header}</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.changeHeader.bind(this)} className="change-header-form">
                <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>  
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

At first, when I clicked submit, nothing happened and I got an error in the console that says

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null`

I then realized I needed to bind the `changeHeader` function to `this` which I changed so before I had:

```
<form onSubmit={this.changeHeader}...
```

changed it to

```
<form onSubmit={this.changeHeader.bind(this)}...
```

After doing this, the error cleared but my header is still not updating.[I read that](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e) there has been strong suggestions against changing state via setState is bad practice because calling `setState()` again could potentially alter the changed state. `setState` is also an asynchronous operation which would also explain why my header isn't changing.

With all that said, then what would be the best way to handle this? From what I understand, `props` wouldn't make sense either since those values are stored directly in your component and aren't parameters that can't be dynamically updated. I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between these different data types and how they are handled in the DOM.

Comment: Use `ref` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html instead of document.getElementById;

Comment: `value` is not a function `const newHeader = document.getElementById('input').value;` and you really should avoid quering the DOM by using element refs or making controlled input.

Comment: Or, use controlled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: And don't forget to check the value emptiness before sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting state incorrectly. 
More over to get the data from input fields you can either use `controlled` input elements(via states) or `uncontrolled` input elements via **"ref"** which I have used in below example.

In controlled input element you store the value of input element in state and changes to that value is done by calling `onChange` method and then setting the state via `this.setState({})`.

Calling `setState` causes re-rendering to happen and `dom` gets the updated data based on new state.

Btw **"refs"** gets you the direct access to dom elements, in similar way `$()` was used in `jquery` and should be avoided if possible because it will lead to very hard to manage and predict `dom` changes.

Also there are cases where use of "refs" is recommended

There are a few good use cases for refs:

- Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
- Triggering imperative animations.
- Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {header: 'yeaheheh'};
  }
  changeHeader = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    let newHeader = this.textInput.value;
    console.log('submitted');
    this.setState({header : newHeader});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h1>{this.state.header}</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.changeHeader} className="change-header-form">
                <input id="input" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Why use `ref` when you can just as easily make the input a "Controlled Input"? I don't think this is what `ref` should be used for.

Comment: Yes there is no need to do that. I am trying to explain that there is another way as well :)

Comment: Thank you @WitVault I was having a hard time understanding how that worked. This really clears things up a lot.

Comment: @WitVault is it safe to say this was a good instance of using "ref"?

Comment: @kawnah not according to the Facebook docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs

Comment: I would say no. I would prefer setting up local state for each input type in my react component and provide a onChange handler to update the state accordingly. Because does not changes the dom directly and goes through react way.

Comment: So in the future, it looks like getting values should be `input value={this.state.inputValue}` is the best way then.

Comment: @kawnah does any of this helps you?

Comment: @WitVault yes!! Very helpful answer.

Comment: @kawnah Thanks, I think you should then accept at least one of the answers given by others or mine.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `this.setState(newHeader);` with `this.setState({header: newHeader});`.

Comment: This will work but I highly recommend to not use this route. I've never come across a time when I use `document.getElementById` in react.

Comment: @adam-beck I think it's not an issue from topic and added as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article in the react docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components.

Basically what you want to do is create another handler for the input. This will be called every time there is a change to the input field and a property in your `state` will be updated. Then, when you submit the form you can take that new property and "merge" it using `setState` to become the new header.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/beqeziyano/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      header: 'yeaheheh',
      next: ''
    }

    this.changeHeader = this.changeHeader.bind(this);
    this.updateNext = this.updateNext.bind(this);
  }

  changeHeader(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      header: this.state.next
    });
  }

  updateNext(e) {
    this.setState({
      next: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.header}</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.changeHeader} className="change-header-form">
          <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" onChange={this.updateNext} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Maybe this bin will provide a little better context at what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: adding another handler seems like a good solution to the concern I found out about in regards to changing the state directly via `setState()` is that the purpose? But do I really *need* this since getting the value of the input and setting my state incorrectly was the root of the issue?

Comment: If it works it works, I guess. But personally, I would add the handler because it is the "react way". I don't know enough of the internals of react but since the team recommends this method I do my best to adhere to it. It is probably less performant to grab the value out of the DOM element than it is to get it from react's state.

Comment: So I would use `value={this.state.inputValue}` then, or something

Comment: You don't need to unless you want to programatically change the value of the textbox. For instance, setting an initial value or clearing what the user has written. But usually -- yes you would. [See this bin](http://jsbin.com/rucuworoju/edit?html,js,console,output) for what I mean. On submit I'm clearing what the user entered in the textbox by using `this.setState({ header: this.state.next, next: '' });`

Answer (score 0):

There's the small bug in your code preventing it from working (`this.setState(newHeader)` -> `this.setState({header: newHeader});`), but the thing is that your code is not idiomatic for React.

You are supposed to use [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) instead of grabbing the values from the form's inputs on submit, as you would do with jQuery.

"Controlled component" is a silly name for the pattern where an input's state is mapped to the application state, so an input itself behaves as if it would be kinda "stateless". In your case, you need to have separate component state member for every text input you've got. Input control should look like this:

```
<input value={ this.state.inputValue }
       onChange={ e => this.setState({ inputValue : e.target.value }) }
/>
```

Now it's bound to your `inputValue` state member, so you can just take it from the state at any moment you need. On form's submit handler, in your case.

That's it. Your code must be fixed accordingly. Refer to the "controlled components" manual for further details, it's the really important React concept.

Answer (score 0):

You should modified your function like this..

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    _that = this;
  }

  changeHeader = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
    let newHeader = this.textInput.value;
    console.log('submitted');
    _that.setState({header : newHeader});
  }
```